# Invalid syntax when trying to create custom http errors

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to make custom http error pages. And as usual the django docs are really hard to understand.

I'm trying my best to follow this doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

So I have set DEBUG = False

I have set ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

In my views.py (not inside an app)

```
def server_error(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'mysite/errors/500.html')
```

And in my urls.py (not inside an app), after all paths.

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    .......etc

    handler500 = 'mysite.views.server_error'
]
```

When I run my server, I get instant error on handler500 in urls.py.

```
handler500 = 'mysite.views.server_error'
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also made a simple '500.html' under 'templates/errors'.

I have tried with importing handler, even though I read that I should not.
I tried with removing 'mysite' in location for view etc.

I can't seem to find anything about this SyntaxError on my handler?

Comment: Put `handler500 = 'mysite.views.server_error'` outside of `urlpatterns` at file level.

Comment: as simple as that. I already got grey hair from this stupid thing O_o Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Put `handler500 = 'mysite.views.server_error'` outside of `urlpatterns` at file level.

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    .......
]

handler500 = 'mysite.views.server_error'
```

Also add `500` response status in the error view

```
def server_error(request):
    return render(request, 'mysite/errors/500.html', status=500)
```

Comment: Why do I get this though 'TypeError: server_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exception''

Comment: Because you have an extra argument 'exception' from your view function that Django doesn't expect. Remove the `exception` parameter from your `server_error` function